# Jquery Horizontal Scroll, Return to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using this code for horizontal scrolling and it works perfectly, well almost :). I have 3 Div's wrapped in a 300% Div and I'm using anchors to call each div using the horizontal scroll function. The problem I'm having is: let's say one page is 1500px in height, when I click my anchor link (which is a fixed menu at the very top of the page) it scrolls directly over to the next div, but doesn't start at the top where the div is. my horizontal scroll happens exactly where it's at on the screen and then i have to scroll up to see the content. Is it possible to have a link jump to top and then go to the next anchor (joining anchors?)? Here's the javascript that I'm using that i found online.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArKYc/2/)
Here's the Source [Tutorial](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/horizontal-website.php)

```
// JavaScript Document
/* jQuery.ScrollTo - Easy element scrolling using jQuery - Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com - Dual licensed under MIT and GPL - Date: 3/9/2009 - @author Ariel Flesler - @version 1.4.1 - http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html */
;(function($){var m=$.scrollTo=function(b,h,f){$(window).scrollTo(b,h,f)};m.defaults={axis:'xy',duration:parseFloat($.fn.jquery)>=1.3?0:1};m.window=function(b){return $(window).scrollable()};$.fn.scrollable=function(){return this.map(function(){var b=this,h=!b.nodeName||$.inArray(b.nodeName.toLowerCase(),['iframe','#document','html','body'])!=-1;if(!h)return b;var f=(b.contentWindow||b).document||b.ownerDocument||b;return $.browser.safari||f.compatMode=='BackCompat'?f.body:f.documentElement})};$.fn.scrollTo=function(l,j,a){if(typeof j=='object'){a=j;j=0}if(typeof a=='function')a={onAfter:a};if(l=='max')l=9e9;a=$.extend({},m.defaults,a);j=j||a.speed||a.duration;a.queue=a.queue&&a.axis.length>1;if(a.queue)j/=2;a.offset=n(a.offset);a.over=n(a.over);return this.scrollable().each(function(){var k=this,o=$(k),d=l,p,g={},q=o.is('html,body');switch(typeof d){case'number':case'string':if(/^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px)?$/.test(d)){d=n(d);break}d=$(d,this);case'object':if(d.is||d.style)p=(d=$(d)).offset()}$.each(a.axis.split(''),function(b,h){var f=h=='x'?'Left':'Top',i=f.toLowerCase(),c='scroll'+f,r=k[c],s=h=='x'?'Width':'Height';if(p){g[c]=p[i]+(q?0:r-o.offset()[i]);if(a.margin){g[c]-=parseInt(d.css('margin'+f))||0;g[c]-=parseInt(d.css('border'+f+'Width'))||0}g[c]+=a.offset[i]||0;if(a.over[i])g[c]+=d[s.toLowerCase()]()*a.over[i]}else g[c]=d[i];if(/^\d+$/.test(g[c]))g[c]=g[c]<=0?0:Math.min(g[c],u(s));if(!b&&a.queue){if(r!=g[c])t(a.onAfterFirst);delete g[c]}});t(a.onAfter);function t(b){o.animate(g,j,a.easing,b&&function(){b.call(this,l,a)})};function u(b){var h='scroll'+b;if(!q)return k[h];var f='client'+b,i=k.ownerDocument.documentElement,c=k.ownerDocument.body;return Math.max(i[h],c[h])-Math.min(i[f],c[f])}}).end()};function n(b){return typeof b=='object'?b:{top:b,left:b}}})(jQuery);

/* jQuery.LocalScroll - Animated scrolling navigation, using anchors - Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com - Dual licensed under MIT and GPL - Date: 3/11/2009 - @author Ariel Flesler - @version 1.2.7 */
;(function($){var l=location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');var g=$.localScroll=function(a){$('body').localScroll(a)};g.defaults={duration:1e3,axis:'y',event:'click',stop:true,target:window,reset:true};g.hash=function(a){if(location.hash){a=$.extend({},g.defaults,a);a.hash=false;if(a.reset){var e=a.duration;delete a.duration;$(a.target).scrollTo(0,a);a.duration=e}i(0,location,a)}};$.fn.localScroll=function(b){b=$.extend({},g.defaults,b);return b.lazy?this.bind(b.event,function(a){var e=$([a.target,a.target.parentNode]).filter(d)[0];if(e)i(a,e,b)}):this.find('a,area').filter(d).bind(b.event,function(a){i(a,this,b)}).end().end();function d(){return!!this.href&&!!this.hash&&this.href.replace(this.hash,'')==l&&(!b.filter||$(this).is(b.filter))}};function i(a,e,b){var d=e.hash.slice(1),f=document.getElementById(d)||document.getElementsByName(d)[0];if(!f)return;if(a)a.preventDefault();var h=$(b.target);if(b.lock&&h.is(':animated')||b.onBefore&&b.onBefore.call(b,a,f,h)===false)return;if(b.stop)h.stop(true);if(b.hash){var j=f.id==d?'id':'name',k=$('<a> </a>').attr(j,d).css({position:'absolute',top:$(window).scrollTop(),left:$(window).scrollLeft()});f[j]='';$('body').prepend(k);location=e.hash;k.remove();f[j]=d}h.scrollTo(f,b).trigger('notify.serialScroll',[f])}})(jQuery);

/* Fire Horizontal Scroll */
$(document).ready(function () {$.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'x'; $.localScroll(); });
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net of your problem?

Comment: Those are some long lines of code

Comment: Added the JSFiddle of the original source.